# Mathematica variable defined outside Do loop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want mathematica to display the result in decimal form.Say 3 decimal places together with 10 to some power. What function shall I use?

```
r = 0;
Do[r += (i/100), {i, 1, 100}];
Print[r];
```

I tried `ScientificForm[r,3]`and`NumberForm[r,3]` and both do not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have, though you don't quite state this, is that Mathematica can compute `r` accurately.  Your code sets the value of `2` to the rational number `101/2` and Mathematica's default behaviour is to display accurate numbers accurately.  That's what you (or whoever bought your licence) pay for.

The expression

```
N[r]
```

will produce a decimal representation of `r`, ie `50.5` and

```
ScientificForm[N[r]]
```

gives the result

```
5.05*10^(1)
```

(though formatted rather more nicely in the Mathematica front end).

Comment: I notice that you had/have an account at [Mathematica.SE] but you have deleted all of your answers.  Why?